# How to work around tr and cut not being available?

Tags: bash, cut, tr

I don't have `tr` and `cut` available to use. This (extract) works with them on a Linux server:

```
disk_avail=$(df -k /var/tmp | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f4)  
pids=$(cat /var/tmp/$0.pid | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)  
while [ $count -le 4 ]
```

..but when I try implement them on the device it says:

```
tr: not found
cut: not found
tr: not found
cut: not found
[: -lt: unexpected operator
```

Can anyone help me around this please?
I've just checked and sed and awk are available.
The device is a Juniper router running JunOS.
Outputs as requested:

> % ls /bin/cut
>    ls: /bin/cut: No such file or directory
>    % ls /usr/bin/cut
>    ls: /usr/bin/cut: No such file or directory
>    %

Thank you for the awk suggestions below, I'll try them out soonest.

The awk solutions worked thanks!!

Comment: do you have `sed` or `awk` available?

Comment: What is the device? Is it running embedded Linux with a shell like Busybox, or does it run real Bash?

Comment: do you have awk/sed? just type them and see if you get help and option displayed? also paste the output of ls /bin/cut; ls /usr/bin/cut Am sure it would be issue with PATH variable

Comment: What *is* available?

Comment: The `[: -lt: unexpected operator` is probably because `$count` is empty because of the earlier errors. Quoting the argument would avoid that: `while [ "$count" -le 4 ]`

Comment: I've just checked: sd and awk are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is normally available, so supposing you have it in your machine, this approach can help you solve the problem:

```
df -k /var/tmp | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f4
```

This means you want to get, from the last line of `df -k`, the 4th field.

This is a equivalent:

```
disk_avail=$(df -k /var/tmp | awk 'END {print $4}')
```

We are taking advantage of `awk` being able to access to the last line when processing the `END` block. This way, you can print the last 4th field. Also, there is no need to combine `tr -s' '` and `cut`, because `awk` does handle multiple spaces as one.

---

Regarding this one:

```
pids=$(cat /var/tmp/$0.pid | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
```

this gets the 2nd field from `/var/tmp/$0.pid`. Similarly, you can use this awk:

```
pids=$(awk '{print $2}' /var/tmp/$0.pid)
```

---

Regarding the problem with `while [ $count -le 4 ]`, take into account what [Keith Thompson comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717736/how-to-work-around-tr-and-cut-not-being-available/26717808#comment42026618_26717736):

> The `[: -lt: unexpected operator` is probably because `$count` is
>   empty because of the earlier errors. Quoting the argument would avoid
>   that: `while [ "$count" -le 4 ]`

Answer (score 2):

I hope you at least have a proper shell.

Here's how you can (advantageously) replace the external utilities `tail`, `tr`, `cut`, etc. with shell builtins. We assume (at least) a POSIX shell.

- For the first line:

  ```
  disk_avail=$(df -k /var/tmp | { read -r _; read -r _ _ _ d _; echo "$d"; })
  ```

  This line assumes that `df -k /var/tmp` outputs two lines (one for the header, and one for the content), and that your `tail -1` in fact wanted the second line. This is very likely applicable in your case.
- For the second line:

  ```
  pids=$(while read -r _ p _; do echo "$p"; done < /var/tmp/$0.pid)
  ```
- For the last line, as [@Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) commented in your OP, this might be due to a lack of quotes. Use:

  ```
  while [ "$count" -le 4 ];
  ```

  At least you'll get a different error in this case—maybe something like `[: Illegal number:`.

You tagged your question Bash. If you *really* have Bash installed, these commands can be written in a better style.